# Проблема с кодировкой записываемой строки через Update

Tags: sql-server

Записываю в столбик `userFirstName NVARCHAR (MAX)`

```
string s = "UPDATE InfoID SET " + pole + "='" + data + @"' WHERE ID = " + id;
```

В итоге : `UPDATE InfoID SET userFirstName = 'Ариша' WHERE ID = 111`

Но записываться не `Ариша`,а `?????` Как это исправить?

Comment: Не склеивайте SQL руками через +, используйте параметры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE InfoID SET userFirstName = N'Ариша' WHERE ID = 111`

так сработает. для работы с NVARCHAR и NCHAR, перед текстом нужно поставить символ `N`